# for loop across two ID columns

Tags: r

I am trying to create a basic for loop function to print the summary statistics of some data. I have two ID variables

```
k <- unique(df$ID_1)
m <- unique(df$ID_2)

func <- 
  for (i in 1:k) {
  for (j in 1:m) {
    tmp[i] <- summary([[i]])
    print(tmp[i])
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with the `j in 1:m` part of the loop and how to handle it to print the summary statistics.

I have:

`for i in 1:k(countries)`
`for j in 1:m(industries)`
`print summary statistics for each i across j` essentially saving it in a new dataframe.

Just a little unsure how to handle the `j` part in this for loop.

Here is the first 40 observations of a random sample of the data:

```
df = structure(list(Major.sectors.id = c(13L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L,  11L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L,  2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 16L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 2L,  7L, 7L, 5L, 5L), Region.in.country.id = c(14L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L,  2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 15L,  1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 10L,  12L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 10L), CL.CA
= c(0.760887885213847, 1.65052687741763, 
0.0806197205130879, 0.81806086270666, 0.288078797135706, 4.40245492070389, 
1.04708699122107, 0.303834508544838, 0.660743728653869, 0.588710351051974, 
0.798830178759201, 0.927690515241424, 0.425398597752096, 3.94063680888526, 
0.23268050036403, 0.0476527647463019, 0.793725271068126, 7.57011718390699, 
0.313488176978694, 0.932388646476865, 0.528403681370993, 0.327018095170076, 
0.026490765171504, 0.0684209603311003, 0.199002799160252, 1.39359718123149, 
1.46636993076162, 1.4949863023741, 0.950167224080268, 0.976629282263177, 
0.0311026456992869, 0.850753860127157, 1.13918820019141, 0.801954640022603, 
71.4120603015075, 1.81240164673211, 0.813709616403117, 1.16837699936937, 
0.535646685572253, 0.54046260697011), WC.TA = c(0.912151080743853, 
-0.149811669390946, 0, 0.317269061162005, 0.404991527614234, 
0.0917180013689254, 0, 0.0363331984252548, 0.0581172322430804, 
0.0984968038873609, 0.404607993560882, 0.429639957001037, 0.0310040298241571, 
0.51689621232918, 0.20287556599724, 0.0768790516016589, 0.470663333767837, 
0.115332950488128, 0.959409600460894, 0.810159261144644, -0.000968329915698337, 
0.276768734669129, -0.00197889182058048, 0.841627179101607, 0.337732164517433, 
0.0312224689196786, 0.0905910619894282, 0.554192762156444, 0.0112172829248027, 
0.365589304257529, 0.155960321393463, 0.781180744777475, 0.129165904803528, 
0.815471911266304, -0.0833032382328157, 0.312503120641987, 0.637601499063086, 
0.482001582278481, 0.344956547341399, 0.142965448177925)), .Names = c("Major.sectors.id",  "Region.in.country.id", "CL.CA", "WC.TA"), row.names = c(102291L,  68029L, 67292L, 101860L, 94123L, 77664L, 18713L, 39361L, 61163L,  96185L, 92109L, 5411L, 52390L, 95008L, 12084L, 82522L, 102897L,  61661L, 33672L, 89727L, 76163L, 25942L, 10525L, 38400L, 24587L,  33894L, 20545L, 20563L, 10163L, 55586L, 77839L, 59394L, 86677L,  43471L, 77523L, 2190L, 61390L, 77768L, 95584L, 70096L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT @nate.edwinton : for comment below;

Using the `dput`output in the original post I run the following code:

```
k <- unique(df$Major.sectors.id)
 m <- unique(df$Region.in.country.id)

    colnames(df)
     for(i in 1:length(m)){
       country.ID <- m[i]    # provided ID_2 corresponds to countries
       for(j in 1:length(k)){
         sector.ID <- k[j]   # provided ID_1 corresponds to sectors
         S1 <- which(df$Major.sectors.id == sector.ID)
         S2 <- which(df$Region.in.country.id == country.ID)
         rows.2.consider <- intersect(S1, S2)
         tmp.summary <- summary(df[rows.2.consider,])
         print(tmp.summary)
         rm(country.ID, sector.ID, S1, S2, rows.2.consider, tmp.summary, i, j)
       }
     }
     `
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the for loop, it should be `for (i in 1:length(k)){}`, my question is: `k` and `m` are vectors?

Comment: So you have a data frame and you want to get summary statistics for each subset of that data frame given by the combinations of country and industry?

Comment: `k` and `m` and vectors `1-13`and `1-14`. I have a data frame and yes I am trying to get summary statistics for each country and each industry in that particular country. So I will essentially like to create a matrix with dimensions `1-13` by `1-14` (so 183 values).

Comment: To keep it simple, a matrix of the mean values of each column across each country and industry.

Comment: Can you put some sample of your data?

Comment: Sure, 2 minutes!

Comment: of the top of my head I would recommend to switch `for(i in 1:k)` with `for(i in 1:length(k))` and similarly for `j`, as from the looks of it `i, j` are no integers.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested and it does make more sense. Also:
`k <- unique(df$Major.sectors.id)` and
`m <- unique(df$Region.in.country.id)`

Comment: Hi, it is not clear the part "I have.." can you put you code correctly indented?

Comment: 2 further questions: `j` seems to be unused in your loop, is this on purpose? Also, what do you wish to take the `summary` of? (What data frame/matrix/list/etc. Is it `df`?)

Comment: Sure! I am trying to say that for each `country` for countries `US`, `ÙK`, `Germany`... etc. (1-13) take the `US` and with the `US` subsample take a specific industry `Industry1` and calculate the mean. Then take the `US` again and do the same for `industry2` etc... then go to the `UK ` and take `Industry1` mean, `industry2` mean etc... and do this across all countries and for all regions and industries. hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: @nate.edwinton `j` is unused since I do not know how to handle it in the for loop function. To keep things simple for now I want to just calculate the mean for each country´s industry.

Comment: I see. I fail to see the different countries and industries in the code you provided. Maybe provide us something like `str(df)` (where `df` denotes your data frame).

Comment: I have assigned unique ID´s to each industry and to each country (i.e. just a number) so the `US`would be a `1` for instance and the `UK` a `2`. so for industry `8` in the `UK` would have, values `2` and `8`.

Comment: Here is the `str(df)` of the whole dataset

`'data.frame': 106057 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Major.sectors.id    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 3 ...
 $ Region.in.country.id: int  1 2 2 2 3 1 4 3 2 3 ...
 $ CL.CA               : num  3.75 1.88 1.17 1.38 3.73 ...
 $ WC.TA               : num  -0.07865 0.52677 0.7289 0.1257 0.00637 ...`

Answer (score 1):

So this might help you

```
for(i in 1:length(m)){
  country.ID <- m[i]    # provided ID_2 corresponds to countries
  for(j in 1:length(k)){
    sector.ID <- k[j]   # provided ID_1 corresponds to sectors
    S1 <- which(df$ID_1 == sector.ID)
    S2 <- which(df$ID_2 == country.ID)
    rows.2.consider <- intersect(S1, S2)
    tmp.summary <- summary(df[rows.2.consider,])
    print(tmp.summary)
    rm(sector.ID, S1, S2, rows.2.consider, tmp.summary, j)
    }
   rm(country.ID, i)
 }
```

---

**Update**

Here a portion of the output:

```
 Major.sectors.id Region.in.country.id     CL.CA            WC.TA       
 Min.   :13       Min.   :14           Min.   :0.7609   Min.   :0.9122  
 1st Qu.:13       1st Qu.:14           1st Qu.:0.7609   1st Qu.:0.9122  
 Median :13       Median :14           Median :0.7609   Median :0.9122  
 Mean   :13       Mean   :14           Mean   :0.7609   Mean   :0.9122  
 3rd Qu.:13       3rd Qu.:14           3rd Qu.:0.7609   3rd Qu.:0.9122  
 Max.   :13       Max.   :14           Max.   :0.7609   Max.   :0.9122  
 Major.sectors.id Region.in.country.id     CL.CA         WC.TA    
 Min.   : NA      Min.   : NA          Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA      1st Qu.: NA          1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA      Median : NA          Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN      Mean   :NaN          Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA      3rd Qu.: NA          3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA      Max.   : NA          Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA
```

The way I see it, the explanation for all these `NA`s and `NaN`s is fairly simple: The loop runs through all possible (`country.id`, `region.id`) combinations. However, for some combinations there is no data, e.g. there is a row in `df` corresponding to `sector.id == 13` and `region.id == 14`, however there is no row with `sector.id == 6` and `region.id == 14`. This explains the `NA`s in the second summary above.

I am still a bit puzzled by the `NaN` in `Mean` (I'm asking myself why not `NA` as in `Median`), but I guess it has something to do with the way the function is defined.

Finally, the reason `sum(is.na(df))` returns `0` is that there is no `NA` in `df`! <s>Indeed, `which(is.na(df)==TRUE)` returns `integer(0)`. So in other words, you are summing up over nothing.</s> `is.na(df)` is a logical vector consisting of `TRUE`s or `FALSE`s. Here, because there is no `NA` in `df`, it consists only of `FALSE`s. Now, these logical operators can be used to perform mathematical operations: `TRUE` is then seen as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`. This explains it.
And if one tries to sum up `NA`s, one obtains the following: `sum(c(NA,NA))` returns `NA`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code! I think this is certainly the right direction but I am running into a few errors still (I think that its simply because I renamed a few variables along the way (i.e. `df$ID_1` assigns to `df$Region.in.country`)) I will try to tweek your code a little more.

Comment: Error message I obtain: `Error in which(df$Region.in.country.id == country.ID) : 
  object 'country.ID' not found `

Comment: `country.ID` should be defined in line number 2 of the above code. Did you keep the same order as above?

Comment: Code too long to post here so check Original comment for the EDIT.

Comment: Alright I made a slight mistake, remove the `i` and the `country.ID` from `rm(...., i, j)`, then it should work (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance I really appreciate it! I am able to run the code sucessfully however it only returns `NA` values. When I run `sum(is.na(df)) I obtain a `0`but in the summary statistics I get `NA` and `NaN` values.  I will look a little further into whether some variables are character, factor variables etc. Thank again! EDIT: All variables are numeric, but still obtaining `NA` values and `NaN`values (do you also get the same? I will take a look to see how to correct these problems.

Comment: See my edit for my output and for my interpretation/explanation concerning the `NA`s

Comment: Thanks again for your advice! You are right that there is missing data which explains the `NA`s in a region. For instance, there may be a full dataset for the `US` in all industries however due to the spacity of the data there is data missing in the `UK` in the `industry_wood_flooring` etc.  So this should explain `NA` values. ´NaN´ - i don´t know. but I thank you for your assistance thus far it has been a great push in the right direction.

Comment: Actually: in the full dataset there is missing data, in the sample date this is not the case

Comment: You can add a line like `if(length(rows.2.consider) > 0){...}` before the `tmp.summary` and `print`, that way you will only `print` when there will be actual data.

Comment: THANKS! again, I have been playing with the data and now I believe that I have a working model! One final question. I am trying to save the outputs to double check they are correct (i.e. across region and sector) into a df. Adding `output <- rbind(output, tmp.summary[i,j])` after `rows.2.consider <- intersect(S1, S2)` returns an error.

Comment: I don't have any pc to test it at the moment. But your idea looks good. You should however define `output` before the loop, e.g. `output <- data.frame()`

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggest but unfortunately it did not work, will keep at it tomorrow!